# How to use socket.io with localStorage item as query value?

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, local-storage

#### Objective

---

I want to pass a token from localStorage to verify user's identity during a socket.io connection.
For that I follow [the documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-initialization/#query) and initialize `io()` outside of `MyComponent` and add the token as a `query` :

```js
const token = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');
const test = "hello world";

const socket = io(
  process.env.REACT_APP_API_ADDRESS_HOST,
  {
    query: { token }, // <-- null
  },
);

console.log(token) // <-- null
console.log(test) // <-- "hello world"


export const MyComponent = () => {
    ...
}
```

#### Issue

---

The problem is since this code is **outside** of `MyComponent` it will run during app initialization, at which point the `'refresh_token'` isn't even in `localStorage` yet, so it is **`null`** unless I manually refresh the page.

#### Attempts

---

I thought about initializing `io()` inside `MyComponent` but I don't think I can, else it would either run on every render, or if I put it inside a `useEffect()` then it won't be accessible inside other functions/useEffects.

Comment: @Jlove I'm not sure I understand what that would look like

Comment: I'll add an answer so I can include some formatted code @Monstar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I began typing this answer, I realized that the best situation is likely to combine state & useEffect:

```
const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
  setSocket(io(
    process.env.REACT_APP_API_ADDRESS_HOST,
    {
      query: { token },
    },
  ))
}, [token])


export const MyComponent = () => {
    ...
}
```

My previous comment was misleading so I'll delete that.